# truncate decimal places in SQL server query not returns exact value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select round(convert(float, 7.10), 2, 1) As Amount

Result
--------
 7.09
```

Why the result is coming as 7.09?

I want the result should be 7.10

Comment: Because you're using `float`, it's an awful datatype as it's not accurate and has rounding issues, among other problems. Use `decimal`.

Comment: Which one is available in database ?

Comment: @RAJNIKPATEL both `float` and `decimal` are datatypes in SQL Server. Not sure what you're asking there.

Comment: @Larnu It mean in database there is `7.09` or `7.10` ?

Comment: I would suggest `7.10` @RAJNIKPATEL , as that's the literal value that are using in their example. If the value was `7.09` then why are they supplying `7.10` as the literal value? It also makes their question mute, as you would want `7.09` to equal `7.09`; if they isn't your intended behaviour then the problem isn't SQL Server, it's the inherent flawed understand that a single number (not an expression or equation ) is only equal to itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to convert to a decimal:

```
Select convert(decimal(4, 1), 7.10) As Amount
```

A decimal stores a number exactly -- up to the given number of decimal places.  In addition, it *changes* the type of the result, to contain this information.  `round()` merely changes the value but not the type.

Comment: Perfect..!
But I have another doubt.

Select convert(decimal(4, 2), 7.108) As Amount; 
It returns 7.11.

I want to return 7.10.
How?

Comment: @SukeshChand . . . You can `round()` or `floor()` before the `convert()`.

Comment: If I round 7.108. It will again convert to 7.11. But I want only 7.10.

Answer (score 2):

Try using numeric type:

```
Select round(convert(numeric(10,2), 7.10), 2, 1) As Amount
```

[here](http://rextester.com/YPUDG51805) you have a test!

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment, however, it's easier to convey as an answer:

I think we really need more scope here. The literal value `7.10` would be interpreted (by SQL Server) as a `decimal(3,2)`, which (on it's own) means that a simple `SELECT 7.10;` would return the value the OP is after.

This suggests that they actually have a column with the datatype `float`. If the OP just needs this for a single statement, then just converting their column to a `decimal(3,2)` (may need larger scale) would be sufficient:

```
CREATE TABLE #sample (floatcolumn float);
INSERT INTO #sample (floatcolumn)
VALUES (7.10),(9.767);

SELECT CONVERT(decimal(3,2),floatcolumn) AS decimalcolumn, floatcolumn
FROM #sample;

DROP TABLE #sample;
```

This doesn't, however, inherently fix the OP's datatype choice in their table. Ideally, then, they should be creating a new column and then using that going forward. Maybe something like:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE SampleTable (yourcolumn float);
INSERT INTO SampleTable (yourcolumn)
VALUES (7.10),(9.767);

ALTER TABLE SampleTable ADD yourcolumn2 decimal(10,3);

UPDATE SampleTable
SET yourcolumn2 = yourcolumn;

ALTER TABLE SampleTable DROP COLUMN yourcolumn;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.SampleTable.yourcolumn2','yourcolumn','COLUMN';

SELECT *
FROM SampleTable;

DROP TABLE SampleTable;
```